# MS Access + Sharepoint LInked table with Multi-value field convert to Local Table

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint-2010

Using Access 2013, Sharepoint 2010 OnPremise

I have an Access database that uses Sharepoint 2010 for a back end using Linked Tables.

A few months ago there was a request to have a field contain multiple values, and I stupidly implemented that change, not fully understanding all the issues behind that.  Initial research lead to it being "ok" for Sharepoint Lists.

Due to the company architecture, this application needs to be accessible on a Kiosk machine that doesn't have access to the Sharepoint site, but still is connected to the internet.

If the computer runs the application while connected to the internet it will hangup/stall when opening because it's trying to resolve the connection of the linked tables or trying authenticate.

But if the computer runs the application while not connected to the internet it will operate as it should in an offline mode.  All data is accessible.

Since we can't/don't want to disable the internet of the Kiosk machine the solution was to convert all the Linked Tables to local tables and issue it to the machine that way.

But now a few months later when trying to make the offline mode application we get the following error:

**You cannot enter that value because it duplicates an existing value in the multi-valued lookup or attachment field**

I think it has to do with that multivalue field, which has turned into a huge headache, but can't be undone for at least a couple more months.

The Offline mode functionality was created long before the multivalue change, unfortunately that part of the application wasn't tested against this changed field.

So I need to know if there's a way I can convert the table, or if there's another way to Force Access 2013 into an offline mode.

Thanks,
Dennis

Comment: a structure of your table and a sample of data it contains would be helpfull